# Correct Way for Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am beginning to learn threads in Java and I am a bit confused now.
I hope this is the right place to ask.
I made a little program  for testing:

```
public class GetInfo implements Runnable { 
    //private static boolean stopPointerInfo = false;   
    private static  Thread tn; 

    public static void StartPointerInfo() {
        //stopPointerInfo = false;
        tn = new Thread(new GetInfo());
        tn.start();
        System.out.println("After start1");
    }

    public static void StopPointerInfo() {
        //stopPointerInfo = true;
        tn.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //  while (stopPointerInfo == false) {

        while (! tn.isInterrupted() ) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                tn.interrupt(); 
            }
            .
            .
            doSomething
        }
    }
}
```

Because the `run()` method must know which thread is interrupted I must use the global definition of thread `tn`?

Should I use the `interrupt()` method like I did or should I use the boolean variable like in the comments?

With this Method I can't use the `interrupt` and I must use the boolean version because `Runnable r` doesn't know the thread here?

```
public class GetInfo {
    private static boolean stopPointerInfo = false;

    public static void StartPointerInfo() {
        stopPointerInfo = false;
        getPointerInfo();
    }

    public static void StopPointerInfo() {
        stopPointerInfo = true;
    }

    public static void getPointerInfo() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() { 

            @Override               
            public void run() {
            while (stopPointerInfo == false) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
                    .
                    .
                    doSomething
                }
            }   
        };
        new Thread(r).start();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boolean flag solution is fragile as it is not guaranteed that updates will be visible across different threads. To fix this problem you may declare it as volatile, but if you set the boolean flag you don't interrupt the `sleep` call like in first version. Thus using interrupts is preferred.

I see no reason to declare `Thread tn` as static. You may use:

```
public class GetInfo implements Runnable { 
    private final Thread tn; 

    private GetInfo() {
        this.tn = new Thread(this);
        this.tn.start();
    }

    public static GetInfo StartPointerInfo() {
        GetInfo info = new GetInfo();
        System.out.println("After start1");
        return info;
    }

    public void StopPointerInfo() {
        tn.interrupt();
    }
    ...
}
```

And use it like this:

```
GetInfo infoWorker = GetInfo.StartPointerInfo();
...
infoWorker.StopPointerInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `static Thread`.

Within the `run()` method, you need to test whether *the current thread* has been interrupted.  You don't need access to `tn` for that. You can do this like this:

```
    Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();
```

or

```
    Thread.interrupted();
```

(Note that the behavior of these two are different.  One clears the interrupt flag and the other doesn't.)

Alternatively, you could just change the `static` field to an instance field, and make all of the `GetInfo` methods instance methods.  That means you can instantiate multiple instances of `GetInfo` which each create their own `Thread` and hold the reference in the instance field.

---

Two more points:

- The way that you are creating and then disposing of threads is rather inefficient.  (Starting a thread is expensive.)  A better way is to restructure the code so that it can use a [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).
- Calling your methods `StartPointerInfo` and `StopPointerInfo` is BAD STYLE.  Java method names should always start with a lowercase letter.